# Change of basis on a per vector component level

Tags: quantum-state, complexity-theory, linear-algebra, state-tomography

Suppose we have an $n$-qubit quantum state in the computational basis encoded in a classical blackbox function $f(x)$. That is, with $x \in \{0,1\}^n$ we can query $f$ and get the respective coefficient $f(x) = \sqrt{p(x)}e^{i \theta(x)}$. Suppose that due to dimensionality of the state, it is impractical to query $f$ for constructing an entire $2^n$ vector of components.

Given this limitation is it possible to perform the change of basis such that we get a new blackbox function $g(x)$ that yields coefficients w.r.t to the new basis?

Comment: Do you only want to build the state $\sum_xg(x)|x\rangle$, even through a non-unitary mean, or do you want an unitary $U_g$ such that $U_g|0\rangle=\sum_xg(x)|x\rangle$?

Comment: I want the function g which yields coeffs in a new basis without building vectors and matrices of size 2^n. Since the whole thing is classical computation no need to be constrained to unitary operations.

Comment: If you use the Hadamard basis and demand $g(0000..0)$, doesn't that suggest that the classical comutation is just as impractical as constructing the entire vector of $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any strong assumption on $f$, this is not possible. We will prove a stronger statement: it is not possible for an algorithm to reliably predict $\sum\limits_{x=0}^{2^n-1}f(x)$, which corresponds to $g(0)$ for the Hadamard basis. We also assume a real function $f$, which is easier for the algorithm.

With no assumption on $f$, we assume that $f$ is random. It means that after $q$ queries $x_1,\cdots,x_q$, we have in average $\sum\limits_{i=1}^qf\left(x_i\right)\approx\frac{q}{2^n}$. Let us say that $\mathcal{A}(f)$ predicts the value $y$ with probability $p_y$. Clearly, at least one $p_y$ is negligibly small (the max possible for the smallest amplitude is $\frac{1}{2^n}$). We can then define a new function $f'$ such that:

- $f'$ matches with $f$ on the $x_i$
- For an $x_{q+1}$ that hasn't been queried, we define $f'\left(x_{q+1}\right)=y-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{q}f\left(x\right)$
- The current norm of our state is $N=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{q}f^2\left(x\right)+\left(y-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{q}f\left(x\right)\right)^2$, while the sum of every input is equal to $y$. We then choose all the remaining inputs in pairs $(A,-A)$ so that the state is normalised.

Note that $f$ and $f'$ are equally likely to be given to $\mathcal{A}$. However, the algorithm predicts $y$ with negligible probability for $f'$, while this is the correct value, which means it fails for this case.

So it is not possible to predict a single output of the Hadamard basis for a real function. Thus, your case isn't possible either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't quite follow your argument that involved algorithms and randomness. But I got the Hadamard basis part. I wouldn't say it is a strong statement as it only applies to a very specific case of Hadamard basis. What about Pauli basis. Does your argument generalize to conclude that this is completely impossible?

Comment: @MonteNero what do you mean by Pauli basis? The computational basis is the $Z$ one and the Hadamard basis is the $X$ one.

Comment: By Pauli basis, I mean an $n$-qubit Pauli basis. E.g for 2 qubits: we would have $I \otimes X, X \otimes Y$ and so on. Regardless of the semantics, I wonder if what you wrote applies to any basis or a specific choice of basis.

Comment: @MonteNero I still don't understand. For you, what are the basis states of the $I\otimes X$ basis?

Concerning your second question, I think that this reasoning can be applied as long as the unitary matrix of the new basis has at most $\mathrm{poly}(n)$ zeros. Basically, for any column of this matrix with at most $\mathrm{poly}(n)$ *non-zero* entries, the algorithm can query the associated entries and thus compute the expected output. For every column with at most $\mathrm{poly}(n)$ zero entries, the algorithm can not answer by the same argument as in the answer

Comment: @MonteNero Essentially, the logic is that if there's too much information to get, we can find two functions which are consistent with the queries of the adversary but such that in this new basis, their value is completely different. It is thus impossible for such an algorithm to accurately predict the value in the new basis